# flutter debug console showing start ( ************) when do I try to print someting. How to solve this problem?

Tags: flutter

Whenever I try to print something in Flutter, it shows

```
****************************************************************
```

instead of what I want to see in console. I'm facing this problem from last 1 months.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Please 1) try reproducing the problem with a small example: http://sscce.org, 2) show us the code

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.